# Yii ActiveRecord vs Repository patterns

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, repository-pattern

Those methods have both advantages and disadvantages.

I am developing a mid-sized application using Yii.

Yii has adopted the AR pattern and supports it by default. The advantages of using a repository pattern are very clear but the question is: should I really invest time in implementing a repository pattern combined with Yii?

Also I would like to know your opinion regarding this two patterns. I would also like to know why is AR so popular and so frequently used? In my opinion Repository pattern is more flexible, more testable, has a cleaner code and integrates better in an enterprise application.

Should I continue using the AR pattern with Yii?

I'm also thinking about switching from Yii to Laravel. In this moment I won't lose much of my work by doing this.

Answer (score 4):

As for me, ActiveRecord is pretty good in small projects, but for medium or huge apps it is hard to maintain.

## pros of Yii ActiveRecord

1. **Using of Yii AR can speed up coding.** All AR models and controllers can be one-click generated by [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii).
2. **AR is extremely popular.** Almost all developers are familiar with this pattern. New team members dive into the project faster.

## cons of Yii ActiveRecord

In case of Yii, too much logic concentrated in AR model classes:

- Validation
- Find methods
- Business logic

That makes code:

1. **Less readable.** Often AR classes consists of several dozen of unrelated methods. Logic can be decomposed using [behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1) or [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). But in fact it is still really hard to maintain.
2. **Hard to test.**

When the app becomes big enough, the addition layer between Controller and AR model is needed. Repository is a great choice. As for me, I started using repository in Laravel, but now I am using it in Yii 1/2 too.

It is not actually the problem to implement repository in Yii. Yii's AR is very similar to Laravel's Eloquent. It is much harder to force all team members not to work with AR directly, but use repositories instead.

If you have experience in Laravel, I recommend to use it.

Comment: I know this is an old post but would you take time to give example how exactly you've implemented Repository Pattern for Yii2? A code example in a gist for a particular model would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on type of your application:

- Complex business Application (Domain) worth the effort for repository for those reasons:

  1. Testable
  2. Data Source ignorance
  3. Use interfaces to adapt the data source to your domain
- Small Application (basicaly CRUD) just go with active record repository could overkill.

I use Yii2 active Record decorated in repository implementation, in reality with Yii2 you can have a real repository implementation because you can use ActiveQuery instead of the ActiveRecord class itself, ActiveQuery can return raw array data :

```
namespace app\clean\infrastructure;
class ActiveRepository implements ActiveRepositoryInterface
{
   protected $activeRecordClass;
   protected $query;
   protected $factory;

   function __construct($activeRecordClass)
   {
     $this->query = new ActiveQuery($activeRecordClass);
     $this->factory = new TheEntityFactoy;
   }

   public function findAll(){
     $data = $this->query->asArray()->all();
     return $this->factory->create($data);
   }


}
```